# Symfony 2 : how to override repository of another bundle

Tags: symfony, repository, overriding

I have 2 bundles and i want to override the repository of one of them in the other :

I have a source bundle : SourceBundle. 
I have my override bundle : OverrideBundle

First, in OurVendorOverrideBundle.php, I added :

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'SomeVendorSourceBundle';
}
```

Then

I wanted to add a custom method for the repository of an entity of  SourceBundle.
The source entity is Response.php, and its repository is ResponseRepository.php

So i did :

```
<?php
namespace OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Repository\ResponseRepository as BaseRepository;

class ResponseRepository extends BaseRepository
{
    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getQueryExerciseAllResponsesForAllUsers($exoId)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
        $qb->join('r.paper', 'p')
            ->join('p.exercise', 'e')
            ->where('e.id = ?1')
            ->andWhere('p.interupt =  ?2')
            ->setParameters(array(1 => $exoId, 2 => 0));
        return $qb->getQuery();
    }
}
```

If i dont set the Entity in the OverrideBundle i have this error :

```
The autoloader expected class "CPASimUSante\ExoverrideBundle\Entity\Response" to be defined in file "/home/www/myproject/vendor/ourvendor/override-bundle/OurVendor/OverrideBundle/Entity/Response.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

The SourceBundle entity is :

```
<?php
namespace SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Repository\ResponseRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="source_response")
 */
class Response
{
  ... 
}
```

So i add the Entity in the OverrideBudle :

```
<?php
namespace OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response as BaseEntity;
/**
 * SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Repository\ResponseRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="override_response")
 */
class Response extends BaseEntity
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

But then i have this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT u0_.id AS id0, u0_.ip AS ip1, u0_.mark AS mark2, u0_.nb_tries AS nb_tries3, u0_.response AS response4, u0_.paper_id AS paper_id5, u0_.interaction_id AS interaction_id6 FROM ujm_exoverride_response u1_ INNER JOIN ujm_paper u2_ ON u0_.paper_id = u2_.id INNER JOIN ujm_exercise u3_ ON u2_.exercise_id = u3_.id WHERE u3_.id = ? AND u2_.interupt = ?' with params ["1", 0]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u0_.id' in 'field list'
```

This seems that fields in the table are not found. So i changed to

```
<?php
namespace OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response as BaseEntity;
/**
 * SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Repository\ResponseRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="source_response")
 */
class Response extends BaseEntity
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And it worked.

...But when i reinstalled the bundle, to test if everything was ok i had this **fatal error** stating that **source_response is already defined** (which is, indeed).

So what can i do then ?

I have also read that i can't override an entity unless the source extends MappedSuperclass, in my case, it doesn't.

But i am doomed if i only want to override its repository ? Is it possible ? If then, what is the right way ?

If i remove altogether the annotation for the override entity, i have  :

```
Class "OurVendor\OverrideBundle\Entity\Response" sub class of "SomeVendor\SourceBundle\Entity\Response" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
500 Internal Server Error - MappingException
```

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine mapping in another bundles can be overriden on entity class metadata loading.

### EventListener

```
<?php

namespace Lol\RandomBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class ClassMetadataListener
{
    /**
     * Run when Doctrine ORM metadata is loaded.
     *
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if ('AnotherLol\AnotherRandomBundle\Entity\Response' === $classMetadata->name) {
            // Do whatever you want...
            $classMetadata->customRepositoryClassName = 'ThirdLol\SomeBundle\Repository\NewResponseRepository';
        }
    }
}
```

### Service configuration

```
services:
    lol.random.listener.class_metadata:
        class: Lol\RandomBundle\EventListener\ClassMetadataListener
        tags:
            -  { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```