# Symfony override third party entity repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, overriding

I'm using a third party bundle with a custom doctrine entity repository. It includes a function which I'd like to override to customize it for my needs.
Has anyone ever done this? I couldn't find any documentation on overriding an entity repository.
Why I need to do this: a Service from that third party bundle calls this repository function and executes it. But I'd like to change one part of it.

What I tried:
create an own Entity repository class:

```
namespace NotificationBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\Email;
use Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\EmailRepository as BaseRepository;

class EmailRepository extends BaseRepository
{

    public function markCompleteSending(Email $email)
    {
        $email->setStatus(Email::STATUS_COMPLETE);
        $email->setSentAt(new \DateTime());
        $email->setErrorMessage('');
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->remove($email);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

it extends the parent repository and overrides only this function, the rest I didn't touch. I then registered that repository as a service.
Anyway it's not working!
Anything else needed? Please let me know! I'd be glad about some help.

**where the functino is called:**

```
public function flushQueue(Swift_Transport $transport, &$failedRecipients = null)
{
    if (!$transport->isStarted())
    {
        $transport->start();
    }

    $count = 0;
    $emails = $this->repository->getEmailQueue($this->getMessageLimit());

    foreach($emails as $email){
        /*@var $message \Swift_Mime_Message */
        $message = $email->getMessage();
        try{
            $count_= $transport->send($message, $failedRecipients);
            if($count_ > 0){
                $this->repository->markCompleteSending($email);
                $count += $count_;
            }else{
                throw new \Swift_SwiftException('The email was not sent.');
            }
        }catch(\Swift_SwiftException $ex){
            $this->repository->markFailedSending($email, $ex);
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

that's the class **DatabaseSpool** that is the registered as the service which spools for my swiftmailer.

Comment: I guess you need to open an issue on vendor's git repo for this feature

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ok. I'd think that this is a more general thing?

Comment: Where the code is called?

Comment: @Tokeeen.com I added the function where the code is called! :)

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250665/symfony-2-how-to-override-repository-of-another-bundle

Comment: @Mz1907 Yes I've seen that. The thing is, that I don't get an error message, it's just not overriding. So what I customized in my function is not being executed. So there are no errors, just the service not realizing that this function is overriden..

Answer (score 0):

To override repo of [DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle](https://github.com/dextervip/DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle) i can see [(on git)](https://github.com/dextervip/DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml) that vendor has defined `Citrax\Bundle\DatabaseSwiftMailerBundle\Entity\EmailRepository` as a service named as `repository.email` and you can override services using symfony's [`CompilerPassInterface`](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/compiler_passes.html). In your bundle under `DependencyInjection` folder create your compiler pass and override `repository.email` service by defining your repo which should extend vendor's repo.

```
namespace Your\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use NotificationBundle\Entity\EmailRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('repository.email');
        $definition->setClass(EmailRepository::class);
    }
}
```

> As per official docs
>
> *If you want to modify service definitions of another bundle, you can use a compiler pass to change the class of the service or to modify method calls. In the following example, the implementing class for the original-service-id is changed to Acme\DemoBundle\YourService.*

For more information have a look at [Services & Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/override.html#services-configuration)